# how to calculate spark of a given matrix

Tags: matrices

The spark of a $m\times n$ matrix $ H $ is the smallest number $k$ such that there exists a set of $k$ columns in $H$ which are linearly dependent. This concept is very important in compressive sensing and the tensor CP decomposition. Is there any proper approach to calculate (or obtain) the spark of a given matrix?